# Meteor JS - showing DOM elements on specific templates

Tags: javascript, meteor, onload

I do my first app with meteor js and I need suggestions about showing elements on specific templates. I have header which stays for all templates and content div where templates switches with iron router. I have two buttons on header which wont be shown on some template so I have to hide/show it on specific templates.

Now I made for every template helper function which is attached to main div onload. In that function there are some jQuery hide() and show() functions. I feel it is not the best solutions and I'm quite curious if somebody uses better method to show/hide elements on different templates.

Comment: Can you show how you are doing the routing and template switching? Typically, elements that are repeated on many templates are put in a layoutTemplate in iron router. If some templates do not use the same header as others, just assign them a different layoutTemplate without the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Meteor you typically don't need to do things like attaching to div onload.

Let's say your header has 3 items, one that is always there and two buttons: (leaving out the bootstrap markup for clarity)

```
<Template name="header">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu item</li>
  </ul>
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
</template>
```

Then you can simply define a helper for the header:

```
Template.header.helpers({
  showButtons: function(){
     return (some logic that evaluates to true or false);
  }
});
```

And then modify your header to:

```
<Template name="header">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu item</li>
  </ul>
    {{#if showButtons}}
      <button>Button 1</button>
      <button>Button 2</button>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

No jQuery, no DOM manipulation, no fuss, and completely reactive if some condition in the logic changes and you need to show/hide the buttons while you're still in the same route.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit challenging to make suggestions without knowing the actual use-case (what's shown and hidden based on template).

One approach is to create multiple layouts for each template and map to the right template based on the route:

```
this.route('home', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'home',
    layoutTemplate: 'homeLayout'
});
```

You may also be able to set a data context for the template via router and position it with CSS (so it's not associate with the header template).

```
 this.route('posts', {
  path: '/posts',
  data: function() {
    var foo = 'something';
    return foo;
  }
});
```

You can also set a session variable for each route so that your header helper can access and hide/show based on what's in the session variable.

```
Template.header.helpers({
    someClass: function() {
        var someClass = Session.get('someClass');
        if (someClass) {
          return someClass;
        }
    }
})
```